# Add axis label to bar chart using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I'm creating a bar chart using the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=12pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=150,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits={abs=2cm},
    symbolic x coords={blond, brown},
    bar width = 20pt,
    ylabel= number, 
        ytick align=outside, 
        ytick pos=left,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        legend style={at={(0.04,0.96)},anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize, legend cell align=left,},
        ]    
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue, area legend] coordinates {
        (blond,20)
        (brown,100)};
    \addplot[ybar,fill=purple, area legend] coordinates {
        (blond,110)
        (brown,105)}; 
 \legend{Boys, Girls}  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Hower, I would like to add a label under and in between the x-axis labels as shown in the attached figure. How can I create this label?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need `xlabel` by analogy with `ylabel`. The labels on the x-axis are just tick labels, like those on the y-axis. The fact that they happen to be words rather than numbers doesn't prevent you from also labelling the axis as a whole, just as you can label the y-axis ;). At least, it seems to work for me:

[image: labelled axes]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=12pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=150,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits={abs=2cm},
    symbolic x coords={blond, brown},
    bar width = 20pt,
    ylabel= number,
    xlabel= hair colour,
        ytick align=outside,
        ytick pos=left,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        legend style={at={(0.04,0.96)},anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize, legend cell align=left,},
        ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue, area legend] coordinates {
        (blond,20)
        (brown,100)};
    \addplot[ybar,fill=purple, area legend] coordinates {
        (blond,110)
        (brown,105)};
 \legend{Boys, Girls}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, you have not missunderstood my questions. That's exactly what I wanted. I just started using tikz and thought `symbolic x coords` "overwrites" the `xlabel` option. Thanks!

Comment: @Shery Oh. Fair enough. It was really that your code seemed rather sophisticated in comparison with what seemed a simple solution. Given that I wouldn't know how to draw what you drew, and given that I couldn't even remember the `xlabel` command and didn't read the manual, I didn't expect to come up with something you hadn't! (Also, if it were me, I'd have tried it before posting a question because trying it is very, very low risk. That is, the cost is negligible in comparison with the cost (time & effort) of posting a question here. But I'm always wasting time on ideas which fail, too. :( )

Comment: @Shery I've edited my answer a little: I think the symbolic coordinate thing is just tick labels, just like the numbers on the y-axis. That is, neither stop you from labelling the axis as a whole ;).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have to admit I got most of the code using copy & paste of codes snippets I found on this website :) Now the charts finaly looks like I wanted it to look. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is use of `xticklabel* coordinate system` to put the title of the plot. `clip=false` is required.

```
 \node (title) at (xticklabel* cs: 0.5,25pt) {Hair Color};
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=12pt,
    ymin=0,ymax=150,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits={abs=2cm},
    symbolic x coords={blond, brown},
    bar width = 20pt,
    ylabel= number, clip=false,
        ytick align=outside, 
        ytick pos=left,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        legend style={at={(0.04,0.96)},anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize, legend cell align=left,},
        ]    
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue, area legend] coordinates {
        (blond,20)
        (brown,100)};
    \addplot[ybar,fill=purple, area legend] coordinates {
        (blond,110)
        (brown,105)}; 
 \legend{Boys, Girls}  
 \node (title) at (xticklabel* cs: 0.5,25pt) {Hair Color};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing it this way? I don't really use `pgfplots` so I'm pretty ignorant about it and really just tried `xlabel` on analogy with `ylabel`, but perhaps there are pit-falls I didn't see?

Comment: @cfr your solution is valid. I was working on that too, but you posted first, so I switched focus on the title that I learned before. The scenario is what if `xlabel` had been used and a line of title is needed. Then my solution provides an alternative.

Comment: (+1) Ah, I see. Thank you. I was worried I'd done something obviously bad. And... (+1).

Comment: You are humble. Thank you. I admire your knowledge shown in this site.

Comment: I don't really know anything. I just fiddle... and sometimes things work ;). Anyway, look who's talking about knowledge! [And I really don't use `pgfplots` much at all. So it wouldn't surprise me at all if I did something obviously idiotic with it. I think I've drawn one graph with it ever. And that was probably a copy-paste-modify job.]

Comment: It occurs to me that it is more-or-less impossible to deny being humble, unless, perhaps, you also think that being humble is bad. Then you could arrogantly deny being humble. Otherwise, you are stuck!

Comment: @cfr--You are very good indeed and work hard too. I said what I meant truely in good faith.